# Navigation padding different in cross browser compatibility

Tags: css, cross-browser, navigation, padding

http://danhumphrey.co.uk/nav/main.html

If you open it up in Chrome and Firefox or IE you'll notice I'm having some trouble getting the lis to correctly line up with the nav bar.

I've added padding to the left and right of the li and then tried adding custom padding to one single li. Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove background from your nav element,

2) Add

```
nav ul li {
...
background: #474747
}
```

3) Add this to get your lis to be aligned to nav element

```
#brands {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

4) If you want to adjust your nav height to lis height, increase nav height to 30px, because your lis have 28px height and 2x1px borders which becomes 30px in sum

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a better solution however I'm now having issues in IE. The last item gets pushed onto a second line - is there a fix for this?

Comment: I can't test on IE. Could you try to increase your nav width and test it?